# How can I use bind and unbind with this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, unbind

I have two click functions, one function is for adding vacation in a list, the other function is for removing vacation from the list. When I add vacation to the list, I don't want to be able to click on that specific button again `.ledig-btn`. If I remove a specific vacation from the list, then I want to be able to click that `.ledig-btn` again. I have tried with `jQuery(this).off('click');` and Its working, but then when I remove vacation from the list I want to add the click event again.

```
jQuery(".ledig-btn").on('click', function(event) {
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery(this).unbind("click");
    jQuery('.minlista').append('<tr><td><div class="list-domains" data-id='+id+'><span class="delete-list-domains">X</span>' + '<td class="tld-sok">' + searchWord + '<div class="tld-sok-ilista">' + domain + '</div>' + '</td>' + '</div></td></tr>');
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    jQuery("tr td .list-domains").on('click', function(e) {
        var delRow = jQuery(e.target).closest('tr');
        delRow.remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: _"As of jQuery 3.0, `.unbind()` has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.off()` method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged."_

Comment: @Andreas the OP said *I have tried with `jQuery(this).off('click');`*

Comment: OK, I understand, I will use off and on, but how can I use It in my code?

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your script, you're storing the button id as a `data-attribute` called `data-id`, so we can use it as follow:

```
function myClickHandler(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).off("click");

    //                                                       +--- Data attribute with the  
    //                                                       |    related 'ledig-btn'
    //                                                       v
    $('.minlista').append('<tr><td><div class="list-domains" data-id='+id+'><span class="delete-list-domains">X</span>' + '<td class="tld-sok">' + searchWord + '<div class="tld-sok-ilista">' + domain + '</div>' + '</td>' + '</div></td></tr>');

    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    $("tr td .list-domains").on('click', function(e) {
        var ledigBtnId = $(this).data('id'); // ledig-btn ID
        var delRow = $(e.target).closest('tr');
        delRow.remove();

        // Here we re-bind the click event handler.
        $("#" + ledigBtnId).on("click", myClickHandler);
    });
}

$(".ledig-btn").on('click', myClickHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding/removing the click event on items, you could register a single handler onto a common ancestor using event delegation, then just check the clicked item hasn't already been added to the 2nd list, with the help of the `id` attribute and the `data-id` you use.

**Here is a simplified demo:**

```js
jQuery("#available").on('click', '.ledig-btn', function(event) {
    var btn = jQuery(this), item = btn.closest('div'), id = item.attr('id');
    if ($('#added').find('[data-id="'+id+'"]').length){
      alert('Item already added to the list.');
      return;
    }
    jQuery('.minlista').append(`
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="list-domains" data-id=`+id+`>
            <span class="delete-list-domains">×</span>
          </div>
        </td><td class="tld-sok">` + item.text().replace('Add','')
        + '<div class="tld-sok-ilista">Some dynamic content</div></td></tr>'
    ).find(".list-domains").last().on('click', function(e) {
        jQuery(e.target).off('click').closest('tr').remove();
    });
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

```css
#available, #added{float:left; width:50%; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid black;
margin: 2px; min-height: 10px}
#available div{clear:both; vertical-align: middle}
#available button{float: right}
.delete-list-domains{cursor: pointer; padding:2px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
</p>
<div id="available">
  <div id="v1" class="vacation">Vacation 1<button class="ledig-btn">Add</button></div>
  <div id="v2" class="vacation">Vacation 2<button class="ledig-btn">Add</button></div>
  <div id="v3" class="vacation">Vacation 3<button class="ledig-btn">Add</button></div>
</div>

<div id="added">
  <table><tbody class="minlista">
  </tbody></table>
</div>
```